# Manipulate file from another computer through batch script

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

From my computer, I would like to connect to another computer.
Then I would like to access a file from this computer, make a copy of this file and delete it.

This is my batch script, but it is not working :

```
net use X: \\computer2 passwordOfComputer2 /u:computer2\admin
copy "X:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\myfile.txt" "X:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\myfile.txt.old"
del "X:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\myfile.txt"

pause
```

I have the system error 53.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: check tools the tools the allows you to execute commands on remote machine - `WMIC PROCESS`  ,`WINRS`,`PSEXEC`,`xCMD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work out what error message 53 is, use `net helpmsg 53` - which tells you `The network path was not found.` The reason for this is that you haven't specified a share, just the computername.

Other minor adjustment made to just rename instead of copy/delete - it will be much quicker for large files.

```
net use X: \\computer2\c$ passwordOfComputer2 /u:computer2\admin
ren "X:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\myfile.txt" "myfile.txt.old"

pause
```

Answer (score -3):

Why would you thinking you can make up commands would work?

See `runas /?`

Comment: The commands are valid and they haven't used runas - confused

Comment: Because there is no need to map a drive. You can do it direct, and IF there is a security issue runas will overcome it. And the command isn't correct, by why correct a faulty approach. At it's most simple `move "\\computer2\X$\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\myfile.txt" "\\computer2\x$\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\myfile.txt.old"`